# facebook, how to get many user's profiles details by id's array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How i can get users details in FB by their id?
I have ids array, and i need to get all user's profiles by one query from ActionScript, is it possible?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Comment: Also have a look at FQL you can fetch specific fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is taken from the very [first page of the Graph API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under the 'selection' heading:

> You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the
>   "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL
>   https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in
>   the same response.

This works with the ?fields selector too, so you could also do `https://www.graph.facebook.com/?fields=id,name,picture&ids=<CSV LIST OF IDS>`